# Reading and Writing CSV files in Python

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

I am trying to write the first 3 rows of Vehicle Owners.csv onto Speeding Owners.csv along with the 3rd and 4th line of Speeding Vehicles.csv. However, if there is no speeding vehicle to match the Vehicle Owners, the Vehicle Owners go to missing owners.csv

Can someone please explain why this is not working?

Speeding Vehicles.csv looks like this:

> GH76GHJ,wallace Street,30,35.0
>   GH67MNB,wallace Street,30,35.0
>   GH76GHJ,green street,40,55.9
>   GH76GJ,green street,40,55.9

Vehicle Owners.csv looks like this:

> GH76HJK,1 red street,ross gamble
>   BH98LOP,1 kings road,muammar gaddafi
>   CX87YHJ,1 Alison drive,chandler bing
>   HJ09UJI,6 avenue,idi amin
>   KI59TOM,7 wall street,robert mugabe

My current code is:

```
import csv

with open('Vehicle Owners.csv', 'r') as vehicleownersfile:
    owner_reader = csv.reader(vehicleownersfile)
    details = {row[0].lower(): row for row in owner_reader}

with open('Speeding Vehicles.csv', 'r') as speedingvehiclesfile:
    owner_reader = csv.reader(speedingvehiclesfile)

    with open('Speeding Owners.csv', 'w') as speedingownersfile:
        sowriter = csv.writer(speedingownersfile)

        with open('Missing Owners.csv', 'w') as missingownersfile:
            mowriter = csv.writer(missingownersfile)

            for row in owner_reader:
                detail = details.get(row[1].lower())

                if detail is None:
                     mowriter.writerow(row[0], row[1], row[2])
                else:
                     sowriter.writerow(row[0], row[1], row[2], detail[1], detail[2])
```

Comment: Can you show the output csv you want ? And tell what the problem is (more explicitly than not working) ?

Comment: `writerow()` takes one argument only (an iterable, I believe). So: `mowriter.writerow(row[0:3])` and `sowriter.writerow(row[0:3] + detail[1:3])` might work.

Comment: the program returns this error:_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: The output csv for speeding owners will contain everything from Vehicle Owners.csv and the 3rd and 4th row of Speeding Vehicles.csv. The missing owners output csv will contain all of the Owners Details  from Owners Details.csv

Comment: `detail = details.get(row[1].lower())` should use `row[0]` not `row[1]`, but since the sample data has no matching license numbers, it wasn't caught with the test data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what you are trying to do, but for me, Python (3) shouted that `writerow` takes 1 argument so I had to replace these lines:

```py
mowriter.writerow(row[0], row[1], row[2])
sowriter.writerow(row[0], row[1], row[2], detail[1], detail[2])
```

by

```py
mowriter.writerow(row[0:3])
sowriter.writerow(row[0:2] + detail[1:3])
```

Comment: still returns _csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: Where did you get your CSV ? Try opening it with a spreadsheet editor (like Microsoft Excel or LibreOffice Calc) and saving it again as a csv. There may be some newline format inconsistencies.

Comment: @jsmith0, with the sample data provided and these changes the code works correctly on Python 3.  If you still are having issues provide sample data that reproduces the problem.  Note, however, that files provided to `csv` should be opened with the parameter `newline=''` to correctly handle newlines on all operating systems.